# Can all parameters from axis2.xml be overridden in services.xml

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I've trying to move parameters from axis2.xml to be specific to a single service by putting them in services.xml

I've tried this by moving false
and it doesn't work.

Any tips on what I'm doing wrong? Is there any reason why parameters can't be moved in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of moving the parameter from axis2.xml try to override that same parameter by adding parameter with the same name and a different value in services.xml

Also refer [this](http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/learning-axis2-xml-part1) small tutorial.